# How to append text to end of Ansible task if a variable is defined?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to include `disabled={{ disabled_flag }}` if a user passes `disabled_flag` as an extra var via the CLI. Otherwise, the task wouldn't make any changes.

## task

```
- name: cronjob_1
  cron: minute="*/2"
        name="cronjob_1" user="batch" job="echo $HOME > /tmp/cronjob_1" 
        cron_file="cronjob_1" disabled={{ disabled_flag }}
  tags:
    - cronjob_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a conditional:

when: disabled_flag is defined

Comment: Man, i was overthinking this. Yep, that did it. Sigh ... Thanks